# undefined reference to `lzma_index_end@XZ_5.0'

Tags: caffe

I am trying to install caffe, but I got the following error. Exist solution does not work.

**System info:**

```
  echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
```

**Error:**

```
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_index_end@XZ_5.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_index_size@XZ_5.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_index_buffer_decode@XZ_5.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_stream_footer_decode@XZ_5.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_stream_buffer_decode@XZ_5.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to `lzma_index_uncompressed_size@XZ_5.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tools/CMakeFiles/finetune_net.dir/build.make:133: recipe for target 'tools/finetune_net' failed
make[2]: *** [tools/finetune_net] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:435: recipe for target 'tools/CMakeFiles/finetune_net.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/finetune_net.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: After downloading the newest version of Caffe, this problem have solved.